# a problem about digits of numbers

Tags: number-theory, contest-math

this problem from online math competition *olympiad phystech* 
please help me to solve it.I tried to solve but I am confused in the decision
All six-digit numbers are written in a row in ascending order. Then those of them, in the records of which the numbers $0, 6, 7, 8$ or $9$ are found, are deleted. What number will stand in $5236$ place?

Comment: Welcome to MathSE.  Please write a title specific to your question.  Also, please edit your question to show what you have attempted and explain where you are stuck so that you receive responses that address the specific difficulties you are encountering.  This [tutorial](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference) explains how to typeset mathematics on this site.

Comment: Also:  your header question  seems to require that $0,6,7,8,9$ appear and the question in the body seems to forbid those digits.

Comment: Is this from an on-line math competition?  It's a good practice to state the source of the problem you want help with.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We have 5 digits available (1,2,3,4,5). So there are $5^5=3125$ 6-digit numbers beginning with 1. Then $3\cdot625$ beginning $21,22$ or $23$. Total so far $5000$. Then $125$ beginning $241$. Then $100$ beginning $2421,2422,2423$ or $2424$. Then 10 beginning $24251$ or $24252$. Total so far $5235$. So the number in 5236th place is $$242531$$

Comment: great man,thank you!!!!